# MySQL - Stored Procedure error Operand should contain 1 column

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, temp-tables

I have this stored procedure in MySQL database, but when I test it like below, I get `Operand should contain 1 column(s)` error:

```
CALL `get_strongest_policy_from_all_involved_accounts_for_user`(57);
```

And this is my stored procedure. The code from line 6 to 20 works fine and it returns a table of **0 or more** records.

Can somebody please help me fix the erroras I don't know what causes it. Many thanks!

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `get_strongest_policy_from_all_involved_accounts_for_user` (
  IN app_user_id INT
)
BEGIN
  CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE `ParentAccountPolicies` ENGINE=MEMORY SELECT (
    SELECT UAS.`password_rotation_active`, UAS.`password_rotation_days`, UAS.`Password_minimum_lenght`,
     UAS.`password_must_contain_numeric_char`, UAS.`password_must_contain_lowercase_char`,
           UAS.`password_must_contain_upercase_char`, UAS.`password_must_contain_special_char`
    FROM `user_account` UA, `user_account_settings` UAS
    WHERE UA.`account_id` = UAS.`account_id`
  AND UA.`primary_user_id` = app_user_id
    UNION
    SELECT UAS.`password_rotation_active`, UAS.`password_rotation_days`, UAS.`Password_minimum_lenght`,
     UAS.`password_must_contain_numeric_char`, UAS.`password_must_contain_lowercase_char`,
           UAS.`password_must_contain_upercase_char`, UAS.`password_must_contain_special_char`
    FROM `user_account` UA, `business` B, `app_user_n_business` AUB, `user_account_settings` UAS
    WHERE UA.`business_id` = B.`business_id`
  AND B.`business_id` = AUB.`business_id`
        AND UAS.`account_id` = UA.`account_id`
        AND AUB.`app_user_id` = app_user_id
);

  SET @RotationActive = B'0', @HaveNum = B'0', @HaveLowCase = B'0', @HaveUpCase = B'0', @HaveSpecial = B'0';
  SET @RotationDays = 0, @MinLength = 0;

  IF (SELECT DISTINCT `password_rotation_active` FROM `ParentAccountPolicies` WHERE `password_rotation_active` = TRUE) IS NOT NULL THEN
    SET @RotationActive = B'1';
  END IF;

  IF (SELECT DISTINCT `password_must_contain_numeric_char` FROM `ParentAccountPolicies` WHERE `password_must_contain_numeric_char` = TRUE) IS NOT NULL THEN
    SET @HaveNum = B'1';
  END IF;

  IF (SELECT DISTINCT `password_must_contain_lowercase_char` FROM `ParentAccountPolicies` WHERE `password_must_contain_lowercase_char` = TRUE) IS NOT NULL THEN
    SET @HaveLowCase = B'1';
  END IF;

  IF (SELECT DISTINCT `password_must_contain_upercase_char` FROM `ParentAccountPolicies` WHERE `password_must_contain_upercase_char` = TRUE) IS NOT NULL THEN
    SET @HaveUpCase = B'1';
  END IF;

  IF (SELECT DISTINCT `password_must_contain_special_char` FROM `ParentAccountPolicies` WHERE `password_must_contain_special_char` = TRUE) IS NOT NULL THEN
    SET @HaveSpecial = B'1';
  END IF;    

    SELECT MAX(`password_rotation_days`) INTO @RotationDays FROM `ParentAccountPolicies`;
    SELECT MAX(`Password_minimum_lenght`) INTO @RotationDays FROM `ParentAccountPolicies`;

    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE `FinalPolicy` (
        `RotationActive` BIT,
        `RotationDays` INT,
        `MinimumLength` INT,
        `ShouldHaveDigit` BIT,
        `ShouldHaveLowerCaseChar` BIT,
        `ShouldHaveUpperCaseChar` BIT,
        `ShouldHaveSpecialChar` BIT
    );

    INSERT INTO `FinalPolicy` VALUES (@RotationActive, @RotationDays, @MinLength, @HaveNum, @HaveLowCase, @HaveUpCase, @HaveSpecial);

    SELECT `FinalPolicy`;
END;
```

Comment: Remove the very first `SELECT`

Comment: Removing it causes syntax error in the create command

Comment: Use create temporary table_name as select

Comment: I still get the same error. Sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do something like this:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE `ParentAccountPolicies` ENGINE=MEMORY SELECT (
  SELECT 'a' as x, 'b' as y
  FROM dual
  UNION
  SELECT 'c' as x, 'd' as y
  FROM dual
);
```

This results in the following error:

```
ER_OPERAND_COLUMNS: Operand should contain 1 column(s)
```

[Demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/xcQgnWuACvJcwSEmGSEBcc/0)

The reason is that you have a subselect (subquery in SELECT clause) which **must** return exactly one column and at most one row. But your subselect returns multiple columns.

But you don't need to use a subselect at all. Just remove the outer SELECT like here:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE `ParentAccountPolicies` ENGINE=MEMORY  
  SELECT 'a' as x, 'b' as y
  FROM dual
  UNION
  SELECT 'c' as x, 'd' as y
  FROM dual
;
```

[Demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/qAB1VeD32gwG2jfbKjghNa/0)